How to add a fifth color to an svg mimetic military texture
I have a svg image that simulate a mimetic military texture.
here is the code:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<filter id="a">
<feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" baseFrequency=".02" numOctaves="3" />
<feComponentTransfer>
  <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 1" />
  <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 0 0 1 1" />
  <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1" />
</feComponentTransfer>
<feColorMatrix values="1 0 0 0 0 
                       -1 1 0 0 0 
                       -1 -1 1 0 0 
                       0 0 0 0 1" />
<feColorMatrix values="-.08 .42 .09 0 .08 
                       -.17 .35 -.08 0 .17 
                       -.08 .15 -.04 0 .08 
                       0 0 0 0 1" />
</filter>
<rect width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#a)" />
</svg>

I am wondering if there is a way to add an other color in the mimetic texture
